# An Advanced Query Date Grouping Dilemna

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my Rails app's PostgreSQL DB are records containing hourly prices for the last 10 years:

10(24 x 365)  of these: "12/31/2012 01:00:00", "11.99"

The following query, groups prices by day, averages the prices in those daily groupings to create daily price averages, and returns "day", "daily average" pairs for each day:

```
   HourlyPrice.average(:price, :group => "DATE_TRUNC('day', date)")
```

The problem is, the hourly prices in my source data actually reflect the price for the previous hour.  So, in my data source .CSV, the day starts at the time 01:00:00 and ends at the time 24:00:00.

This conflicts with how PostgreSQL likes to save records in its DateTime column.  Upon importing the CSV data, PostgreSQL converts my records containing the time 24:00:00 to 00:00:00 of the next day.

This throws off the accuracy of my Averaging Query above.  To fix the query, I still want to group by day, but offset 1 hour.  So, that the range averaged starts at 01:00:00 and ends with the 00:00:00 value of the next day.

Is it possible to adjust the above query to reflect this?

Comment: You don't have to add PostgreSQL, Rails, ActiveRecord etc. in the title of your question. People can see what the question is about from the tags. Also adding your name and "Thanks" is not necessary, even [unwanted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). These things have been edited out of some of your other questions, so I thought I should make you aware of this. Other than that, good question.

Comment: Why don't you fix your CSV data to match what the database expects while you're importing it? You don't want your database lying to you and you don't want to lie to your database.

Comment: Thanks mu.  Your input is always appreciated.  I thought about this.  However, my data is taken from a reputable source (public agency) and I don't want to break the format they have.  If I move all dates by one row to suit the db behavior, and someone cross-examines a price record's date with the source for verification of accuracy, it would be off, inspiring confusion and mistrust.  Perhaps I should convert my date column from DateTime to string and retry this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subtract one hour from `date` before applying the `DATE_TRUNC` function to it, like this:

```
HourlyPrice.average(:price, :group => "DATE_TRUNC('day', date - INTERVAL '1 hour')")
```

Comment: You're right Andriy.  Thank you.  That query now goes through thousands of records and creates averages perfectly :)  Great job.  Thanks again.